# Epic badge with too few days hitting the reputation cap?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-badges

Hello again-

I just got the Epic badge (woohoo!), but according to my reputation report:

```
days represented 68
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 48 days
rep cap was exceeded on 48 days
```

Last time I checked, 48 < 50.  This leads me to think that either

1. The reputation report is inaccurate.
2. The code for awarding Epic badges is incorrect.
3. I am missing something here.

Does anyone know which of the three this is?

Comment: Whichever it is, 48/68 is a pretty great rate. Congratulations!

Comment: I think nobody ever gets these badges exactly on time. See e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=legendary

Answer (score 5):

Congrats on getting the Epic badge, it is a really hard badge to get!

There are many little subtleties going on that I should explain.

#### Badges look at current rep levels in the DB

There are certain edge cases where rep levels in the DB do not match the rep report. The rep report show what your reputations **should** be, not what it **is**.

The rep report excludes rep which was gained from deleted posts. Also there are a few edge cases where rep may mismatch due to timing of undoing votes and so on.

Badges query actual data in the DB, they may be out-of-sync with the data in the report.

I performed a recalc on your account (which gave you a bit of rep) so I could analyze this all the way through.

#### The rep report shows a count of the days rep exceeded the rep threshold

So there is a subtle difference here, if you met the rep cap but did not exceed it. The row is not counted in the report:

For example: `-- 2011-01-21 rep +200  = 5760` the missing magic day.

The wording for the badge is "Hit the daily reputation cap" not "Exceeded the daily reputation cap"

I think this semantic diff is kind of pointless, the report should probably count the days the rep is met, however I am not feeling brave enough to play with this code at the moment. (please post a separate request if you think this change is important)