# How is the reputation counted for Badges related to reputation cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

Let's say that i earned 214 reputation today (just a random case ;-)) and i earned 60 of this reputation by accepance of the answers. Should i get the Mortarboard Badge?

As till now i didn't get this badge. In faq its stated that acceptance of questions is immune to the reputation cap. But does this also mean, that it is not counted for "hitting" the reputation cap?

Comment: You should earn the Mortarboard badge whenever you hit 200 or more reputation in the day. Acceptances (and probably bounties) count towards it. All of my Mortarboard badges have been earned in this fashion, before I earned enough upvotes. The effects on the Epic & Legendary badges have been... suspect. I'll see if any conclusions were drawn from the questions.

Comment: Okay thanks ehm... dont know what i should do now, because your commend seems to be the right answer (i just got that badge) but i can't accept it *gg*

Comment: I'm hesitant to post an answer only because I don't have a solid answer about the Epic and Legendary badges, and I'm not really figuring it out from the multitude of posts on it. I'll post what I've got for now, but it'll be subject to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should earn the Mortarboard badge whenever you hit 200 or more reputation in the day. Acceptances count towards it. All of my Mortarboard badges have been earned in this fashion, before I earned enough upvotes.

[I'm drawing from this answer by waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80414/epic-badge-with-too-few-days-hitting-the-reputation-cap/80447#80447), but I believe that the Epic and Legendary badges *currently* require you to get *more* than 200 reputation in a day. Since that is contingent on elements other than upvotes, I am inclined to believe that they do not require you to have gotten the full 200 from upvotes.